# Is there any way to search for all uses of a database table in SQL-Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way to search for the usage of a table in all stored procedures and functions on a sql-server?

Comment: The proposed duplicate has an answer for both functions and procedures (date of the answer `Aug 7 '13 at 15:10` )

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/view-the-dependencies-of-a-table?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: `all uses`, not only in `stored procedures` @Berger

Comment: @KillerQueen : Despite the title, the body of the question restricts the search to "all stored procedures and functions" .

Comment: Oh, ok. I didnt notice this :) @Berger

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id), *
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE definition LIKE '%MY_TABLE%'
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a tool RedGate [SQLSearch](https://www.red-gate.com/dynamic/products/sql-development/sql-search/download) works pretty good for me.